# Database Backup & Restore in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I want to create features, backup & Restore using Codeigniter 4, Is it possible ?

In Guide there is only for getXMLfromResult. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/utilities.html

```
$model = new class extends \CodeIgniter\Model {
    protected $table      = 'foo';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
};
$db = \Closure::bind(function ($model) {
    return $model->db;
}, null, $model)($model);

$util = (new \CodeIgniter\Database\Database())->loadUtils($db);
echo $util->getXMLFromResult($model->get());
```

But i can't get .sql file.

Comment: AFAIK there is no built in Backup or restore function, so you need to write it youself

Comment: to point you into the right direction, check this [codeigniter forum article](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-76241.html), scroll to contribution from Michal_PB1

Comment: also found this: https://github.com/DSB/MySQLDumper but it is archived now, anyway you can get some ideas out of it probably.

Comment: I suggest to write a command for that. You can use `mysqldump` as you see fit.